# What's the meaning of "Bueller" as a joke?

Tags: single-word-requests, metaphors

Somewhere on the [internet](http://www.buzzfeed.com/daves4/brilliant-things?utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=BuzzFeed+731&utm_content=BuzzFeed+731+CID_39575d6e18c4edc4d0cd20c953715742&utm_source=Campaign%20Monitor&utm_term=And%20these%2027%20heroes) I've read about a guy ordering a coffee in the name of "*Bueller*".

Apparently, the cashier called out that name repeatedly.

I've looked up the term but it gave me no clue as to why it's so hilarious. Is that a cultural reference or a linguistic one?!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about explaining a cultural joke.

Comment: Explaining a joke is only on topic if it requires an understanding of the English language. This joke does not. I realise you couldn't know this before asking.

Comment: @MattЭллен You're right. I wasn't sure - in fact I asked whether it was linguistic or cultural thing. Let's close the question. I got my answer anyway so I'm happy.   :)

Comment: English language arises from English culture and lately a lot about US culture. To deny the legitimacy of Ferris Bueller, is to deny the legitimacy of Shakespeare, Poe, Hemingway, Twain. It would be like the anti-US Arabic rap songs, protesting American culture using American culture.

Comment: @BlessedGeek we're not denying anything. This question does not rely on the English language. If the scene were in a film in a different language the outcome would still be the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a trope inspired by the movie "[Ferris Bueller's Day Off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferris_Bueller%27s_Day_Off)". The joke arises from a scene in which a teacher (played by Ben Stein) repeatedly calls Bueller's name when he is taking attendance.

Comment: @GMB - thanks for the edit. I must have been conflating two scenes in my flawed memory. Anyone? Bueller?